# how to loop list by index inside the loop?

Tags: python

how can i loop indexes for "suffixes" variable in "for" loop. For example if suffixes[1](http://s17.postimg.org/vm3d374rz/chart.png), he will print data from list with index1, but i need get all indexes inside "rect" loop, for example in first iteration i need, suffix[1](http://s17.postimg.org/vm3d374rz/chart.png), second, suffix[2],third suffix[3] etc. So right now script write the same text in every bar of chart, but i need for every bar, new value from suffixes list.

```
suffixes = sorted([data[4][14][5:12], data[5][14][5:12], data[6][14][5:12], data[7][14]     [5:12], data[8][14][5:12],
               data[9][14][5:12],data[10][14][5:12], data[11][14][5:12], data[12][14]   [5:12], data[13][14][5:12]])


for rect in rects:
   width = int(rect.get_width())

   if width > 2:
       suffix = suffixes[1]
   else:
       suffix = suffixes[1]

   rankStr = suffix
   if (width < 5):        # The bars aren't wide enough to print the ranking inside
       xloc = width + 1   # Shift the text to the right side of the right edge
       clr = 'black'      # Black against white background
       align = 'left'
   else:
       xloc = 0.98*width  # Shift the text to the left side of the right edge
       clr = 'white'      # White on magenta
       align = 'right'

   # Center the text vertically in the bar
   yloc = rect.get_y()+rect.get_height()/2.0
   ax1.text(xloc, yloc, rankStr, horizontalalignment=align,
        verticalalignment='center', color=clr, weight='bold')

plt.show()
```

Comment: `for i in range(...):`? Could you clarify the problem?

Comment: for example if i will write: for i in range(10): print(suffixes[i]) , he will print only index 10, not every index.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code and data to allow others to recreate the issue - as it stands, I can't tell you what the issue is, and there's a lot of code in your example that seems irrelevant.

Comment: Result of this script is: http://s17.postimg.org/vm3d374rz/chart.png  ,i need to create for every bar different time which i will get from suffixes list, by index.

Comment: please look at: if width > 2:
                    suffix = suffixes[1]
                else:
                    suffix = suffixes[1], he got index1 from suffixes list, and print values of this index inside the bar, how i can change this to print on the bar values, for example: first bar suffixes[0], for second bar suffixes[1], for third bard suffixes[3] etc

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, which counts how many times you have been round the loop:

```
for (count, rect) in enumerate(rects):

     ...
     suffix = suffix[count]
     ...
```

This will give you `suffix[0]` for the first `rect`, `suffix[1]` for the second, and so on.